# Minimum version of Android on devices for Mobile Push

Tags: mobilesdk, android, mobilepush-android, sdk

What is the minimum version of Android on users' devices that MobilePush supports?
I'm using SFMC Sdk for integration into my app.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Line #2 of the documentation: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/

Why not just state it here?  Because it may change over time.